# After the upgrading of Ubuntu to 13.10 and Emacs to 24.3.1, I can't input Japanese and Chinese in Emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, emacs24

I have just upgraded Ubuntu from `13.04` to `13.10` and Emacs to `24.3.1`. It seems Ibus have been made big changes.Then I just go to **system setting -> text entry settings -> add "Chinese pinyin" and "Japanese anty" input method**. It works well when I input Chinese or Japanese in terminal or .txt file. But when I want to input Chinese and Japanese in Emacs. Even though I have enable ibus-mode in the buffer and change to `Chinese pinyin` or `Japanese anty` input method. It just output the English word.

Below is the `ibus configure` in `.emacs`.By the way, Everything goes well before I make this upgrading.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat my-emacs-path "/ibus-el-0.3.2"))
;;(setq ibus-python-shell-command-name "python2.7")
(require 'ibus)
;; Turn on ibus-mode automatically after loading .emacs
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'ibus-mode-on)
(setq ibus-cursor-color '("red" "blue" "limegreen"))
```

I know It maybe not suitable to ask this this question here. But I have already posted this question on `Ask ubuntu`. there is no response.I think maybe someone here have encountered some issue like this before.

Comment: you can try to ask at askubuntu.com

Comment: @farmer1992,yes I have posted this issue to askubuntu site. but There is no response. So I come here to ask help. I have also search this issue on google, There is also no question like this. I wonder why do i get this weird issue...

Comment: This might help a bit, but it doesn't seem to have the answer: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-10/msg00616.html. I seem to recall seeing a similar post somewhere, so maybe searching a bit more will help you.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I will keep on following this issue.

Comment: I ran into the same problem too. Have no way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking 2 hours to find the solution, I get the better way than what I expected-- fcitx.
Using fcitx, you will be able to input Chinese in Emacs with sogou or Google input method. They are much better than ibus, save many hours when typing Chinese articles.
See my blog to know how to use it, I assume you could read Chinses articles. :)
[Ubuntu 13.10 英文版本 Emacs 24.3中文输入](http://blog.csdn.net/csfreebird/article/details/18903755)